# Looking for a simple ssl erlang example

Tags: ssl, erlang, gen-tcp

In the book [*Erlang Programming*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596518189.do) one of the exercises proposed was to print on screen the request coming from a browser using `gen_tcp`. I made it for http requests as follows:

```
-module(tcp).
-export([server/0, wait_connect/2]).

server() ->
    {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(1234, [binary, {active, false}]),
    wait_connect(ListenSocket,0).

wait_connect(ListenSocket, Count) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    spawn(?MODULE, wait_connect, [ListenSocket, Count+1]),
    get_request(Socket, [], Count).

get_request(Socket, BinaryList, Count) ->
    Request = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0),
    io:format("~p~n", [Request]).
```

Now I am wondering how this can be done in case of https request. Can you provide a very simple example, or point me to some resource on books or online?

Comment: Could you post some code for the HTTP version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the user guide for Erlang SSL application:
[Erlang -- SSL User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/users_guide.html)

The guide contains also, in the API chapter, a paragraph on updating existing connections to SSL.

Regarding your code, you should do something like:

- on server and client side you have to issue: 
  `ssl:start()`
- server side: handshake SSL (remember to set 'active' to false for the listening socket)

  `{ok, SSLSocket} = ssl:ssl_accept(Socket, [{cacertfile, "cacerts.pem"},
  {certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "key.pem"}]).`

  where "cacerts.pem", "cert.pem", "key.pem" are files related to SSL certification
- client side: upgrade connection to SSL:
  `{ok, SSLSocket} = ssl:connect(Socket, [{cacertfile, "cacerts.pem"},
  {certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "key.pem"}], infinity).`

As per documentation, now SSLSocket is a ssl channel that can be used to send messages like:
`ssl:send(SSLSocket, "foo").`

Hope this helps!

Comment: in fact i tried something like this, but the problem is that i can't control what the browser is doing...

Comment: sorry, @user601836, but I don't understand the requirement: do you need to integrate the ssl call in Http interface? AFAIK, with the method above you should simply shift the object through with you're dispatching requests from Socket to SSLSocket.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read the following article about SSL sockets in Erang that contains complete code of the SSL echo server and client.

[Erlang SSL sockets example - ssl server & client)](http://erlycoder.com/89/erlang-ssl-sockets-example-ssl-echo-server-ssl-client-)