# Erlang: Connect to API with sockets/gen_tcp

Tags: sockets, ssl, twitter, erlang, gen-tcp

I am new to erlang and programming overall and I am looking for a way to connect to the twitter API by using sockets if there even is a way.
So what I am wondering is, is there anyway to pass http requests/URL in sockets to do so?

I would love any information to read or look at. 
Example code where I can see gen_tcp, socket, ssl or whatever you think is the smartest way to go.
(Of connecting to twitter/sending request).

I do not wish to use another built library unless I really need to.

Thanks in advance,
Erlach

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need HTTP client library. **I do not see any reasons to implement HTTP protocol by your own over TCP-sockets and `gen_tcp`.** Erlang standard library already contains one called [httpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html).

Also there is plenty of third-party http clients for general purposes:

1. [lhttpc](https://github.com/esl/lhttpc)
2. [ibroswe](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse)
3. [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney)

For interaction with API I'd recommend you to take a look at [gun](https://github.com/extend/gun). As project page says, it follows next goals:

> Gun aims to provide an easy to use client compatible with HTTP, SPDY
>   and Websocket.
>
> Gun is always connected. It will maintain a permanent connection to
>   the server, reopening it as soon as the server closes it, saving time
>   for the requests that come in.
>
> All connections are supervised automatically, allowing the developer
>   to focus on writing his code without worrying.

If you need more general information about `gen_tcp` module and network interaction at all, I'd recommend you to start from [this great book](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content).

**UPD:**
More specifically on twitter streaming API (do you mean [this one](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/processing)?). To read streaming data you can use streaming interface of http client:

```
ok = application:start(inets).
{ok, Ref} = httpc:request(get, {RequestURL, RequestHeaders}, [], [{sync, false}, {stream, self}]).
```

After that you will receive following messages into process mailbox:

1. First message will be `{http, {Ref, stream_start, ResponseHeaders}}`.
2. Next messages will be `{http, {Ref, stream, ResponseBodyChunk}}`.
3. Last message will be `{http, {Ref, stream_end, ResponseHeaders}}`.

After you've started such stream, you should just receive incomming messages via **receive** and handle it according to twitter streaming protocol.

Please, refer to documentation about httpc library. You really shouldn't use `gen_tcp` sockets here at all.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Does this mean you recommend I use httpc for connecting and sockets to "stream" what I get or am i mixing these things up?

Comment: Each http client build on top of tcp socket (particulary, they already uses gen_tcp). This means that http client hides from you any tcp-specific details, and you interacting with http client interface ignoring any `gen_tcp`-specific details.

Comment: As basic exaple, you can try following: `httpc:request("http://stackoverflow.com")`. This call will return you HTTP response status, HTTP headers and page body.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about it then if I wish to connect to the twitter api? Would I send an httpc request and then deal with incoming data in a socket recv?

Comment: Im wondering I think the same as this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814695/looking-for-a-simple-ssl-erlang-example?rq=1
Because Im not really sure how I am supposed to go about using other thirdparty clients or libs that you suggest.

Comment: I've updated my answer with example of streaming using httpc library.